# Can't compare string in Django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Here's my template:

```
    <p>{{ instance.video_source }}</p> #"youtube"
    {% if instance.video_source == "youtube" %}
        <h1>YOUTUBE</h1> #doesn't print "YOUTUBE"
    {% endif %}
```

Any idea why the if statement doesn't fire? I've also tried `{% if instance.video_source == youtube|stringify %}`

which is this template tag here:

```
def stringify(obj):
    return str(obj)
```

and the if statement still doesn't fire. And this also doesn't work

```
{% if instance.video_source == youtube|stringformat:"s" %}
    <h1>YOUTUBE</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Here's the origin of `instance.video_source`:

```
@property
def video_source(self):
    return "youtube"
```

Any idea why the if statement isn't working?

**views.py**

```
def article(request, id):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)

    context = {
        'id': id,
        'instance': instance,
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=95)

    @property
    def video_source(self):
        return "youtube"
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load markdown_deux_tags %}
{% load placeholder %}
{% load stringify %}

{% block content %}
    <p>{{ instance.video_source }}</p> #"youtube"
    {% if instance.video_source == "youtube" %}
        <h1>YOUTUBE</h1> #doesn't print "YOUTUBE"
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please show the view, and the model definition for `instance`.

Comment: Added both in my edit.

Comment: Is that the right view? You don't have an instance in the template context anywhere.

Comment: My mistake I've fixed the views now.

Comment: What does the full template look like?

Comment: Added in my edit.

Comment: Any chance the `h1` tag is styled in such a way that it is not seen?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: With everything as you have it above, if `<p>{{ instance.video_source }}</p>` is truly printing `youtube` then I'm struggling to see any reason that  `<h1>YOUTUBE</h1>` would not be displayed. You've inspected the source of the rendered page I presume? You could try using [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) and looking at the `Templates` panel to check nothing weird is happening with your context.